# python still prints line if I specify for it to not do that

Tags: python

I don't think the title really says what my problem is but I don't know how to formulate it.
Anyway, I am printing from a log file all lines then I remember the last line in a variable. I then use a for loop to again go trough the whole file, but I use the fact that it has the time at the beginning of every line to check if the time is bigger then the one from the last line I saved last time I printed all the lines.
Now we get to the problem I have. It still prints the last line even if I don't want it too.
That might be confusing so let me use the output

```py
['16', '31', '18']
[16:31:18] [Async Chat Thread - #121/INFO]: <seba_www> cat?
# the above line is the last line it printed the first time it went trough all the lines
# and I don't want to print it


['16', '31', '19']
[16:31:19] [Async Chat Thread - #121/INFO]: <seba_www> wdasdww
# the above line is the new line I want to be printed
```

I tried to fix it with a simple if statement:

```py
if line != last_line: 
    print(line)
```

but it still prints it...

It might be really messy but I'm gonna put the whole block of code here as well, maybe it will help:

```py
for line in logs:
    print(line)

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    last_line = line
    
    s = last_line.split()
    s1 = s[0]
    if "[" in s1:
        d2 = split(s1)

        d = s1.find("[")
        del d2[d]

        d1 = s1.find("]")
        del d2[d1 -1]

        d2 = listToString(d2)
        lastLine_list = d2.split(':')

        logs = open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'latest1.log'))

        for line in logs:
            s = line.split()
            s1 = s[0]
            if "[" in s1:
                d2 = split(s1)
                
                d = s1.find("[")
                del d2[d]
                
                d1 = s1.find("]")
                del d2[d1 - 1]
                
                d2 = listToString(d2)
                d2list = d2.split(":")

                print(d2list)

                if line != last_line:
                    if d2list[0] >= lastLine_list[0]:
                        if d2list[1] >= lastLine_list[1]:
                            if d2list[2] >= lastLine_list[2]:
                                print(line)
                                time.sleep(5)
    logs.close()
```

Comment: Have you ensured that it's actually the last line, and that it's not a blank line as last line in the file?

Comment: Yes, I have, that is not the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you try this line

```
if line != last_line: 
    print(line)
```

as

```
if last_line not in line: 
    print(line)
```

?

Comment: I worked. Thanks a lot, I still don't know why but it works this way. I'm gonna accept this answer in 3 mins as it doesn't let me right now.